# Matlab script - running an external command (nonblocking)

Tags: matlab

From a script in Matlab, I need to run an external command. Normally this is done with [system](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/system.html), but script execution blocks until the command completes. Is there a way to execute a command from a script without blocking execution?

EDIT: OS is Windows Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows you need to use `start`

```
system('start notepad.exe');
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be overkill, but if you have the full install of matlab, you can use the [Parallel Computing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/) to run the command in a separate thread. It's actually pretty easy to do, the basic syntax would be:

```
obj = createJob();
set( obj, 'FileDependencies', {<list .m files used here>, 'ExampleFileFunc.m'});
task = createTask(obj, @ExampleFileFunc, 1, {4});

submit(obj);                   

waitForState(task,'finished');
varargout = get(task,'OutputArguments');
```

The `{4}` is the number of outputs from `ExampleFileFunc`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bang (!) and then the command, for instance

```
 !vi
```

And to let it run without blocking execution it would be

```
 !vi &
```

The program will show up on a separate screen and you get back to the Command Window so you can continue running MATLAB language statements. It does the same thing for an script so I guess this is what you want to use.